# Excel: Split a 2 column range (A:B) into multiple smaller columns with a pre-set number of rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm struggling with a problem; I'm trying to split two columns (A&B) containing anywhere from 100-1,000 rows of information which need to remain together, into multiple columns containing a pre-set number of rows (Such as 50 rows per).

The following VBA code I found works, but it can only split 1 column into multiple; not 2.
I've attempted merging both columns into one, using the below macro and then using Text to Columns to split the data again, but there's too much manual work involved.

Is there a way to amend the below code, or another alternative VBA code or excel function which may give the results required.

Many many thanks

```
    'Updateby20141106
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Dim OutRng As Range
    Dim xRow As Integer
    Dim xCol As Integer
    Dim xArr As Variant
    xTitleId     = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type: = 8)
    xRow         = Application.InputBox("Rows :", xTitleId)
    Set OutRng   = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type: = 8)
    Set InputRng = InputRng.Columns(1)
    xCol         = InputRng.Cells.Count / xRow
    ReDim xArr(1 To xRow, 1 To xCol + 1)
    For i = 0 To InputRng.Cells.Count - 1
        xValue = InputRng.Cells(i + 1)
        iRow = i Mod xRow
        iCol = VBA.Int(i / xRow)
        xArr(iRow + 1, iCol + 1) = xValue
    Next
    OutRng.Resize(UBound(xArr, 1), UBound(xArr, 2)).Value = xArr
End Sub
```

Intended goal will look similar to this:
[image: Column A & B have been split into 4 columns of 20.]

Comment: Please edit your original question showing what example data looks like and your desired output. Just throwing up VBA without that context is probably going to get your question closed. We are not a script writing service, we are a community of people willing to share our knowledge with others. We appreciate questions that are easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

The code itself for copying data to other cells is very simple, not much different (by size) from the one you took from the macro eight years ago.

As always, when the data for the calculation is specified by the user in a dialog, the biggest part of the code is organizing the dialog and checking the correctness of data entry: did the user close the InputBox with the Cancel button? Did he indicate a whole column with almost a million empty and useless cells? Did he specify the target cell inside the source range? Does the original range contain formulas that are likely to break when moved to another location?

```
Option Explicit
Sub suSplit()
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range, CopyRng As Range, aFormulas As Variant
Dim nRow As Long, nColumns As Long, nRows As Long
Dim xTitleId As String: xTitleId = "SuperUser for Excel"
    Set InputRng = Application.Intersect(Application.Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    On Error Resume Next
        Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Sourse Range:", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
        Set InputRng = Application.Intersect(InputRng, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If InputRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        nColumns = InputRng.Columns.Count
        nRows = InputRng.Rows.Count
        nRow = Application.InputBox("Count of rows (new height):", xTitleId)
        If nRow < 1 Then Exit Sub
        If nRow >= nRows Then Exit Sub
        Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Target Range (single top-left cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
        If OutRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If OutRng.Column + nColumns > ActiveSheet.Columns.Count Then Exit Sub
        If Not Application.Intersect(InputRng, OutRng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo 0
    aFormulas = InputRng.FormulaLocal
    InputRng.Value = InputRng.Value
    Set CopyRng = InputRng.Resize(nRow, nColumns)
    Do While CopyRng.Row <= nRows
        CopyRng.Copy Destination:=OutRng
        Set CopyRng = CopyRng.Offset(nRow, 0)
        If OutRng.Column + nColumns > ActiveSheet.Columns.Count Then Exit Do
        Set OutRng = OutRng.Offset(0, nColumns)
    Loop
    InputRng.FormulaLocal = aFormulas
End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much. I've just got around to editing with an example input/output into the main post as requested and you've already gone and figured it out! Thank you; the dialog boxes I used in the main post required specificying the intended range of cells (not just entire column) but as said it would only work on one column.
Your code provides exactly what I've been after; thanks again.